# youtube embed iframe black box

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ios, youtube

Using JavaScript, YouTube player api, C# asp.net 4.0, MS visual studio 2012.

I have the following wall of JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/swfobject.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.

if (!PreIe8()) {

    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}

// Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
// YouTube player after the API code downloads.
var player;
var vidIndex;
var videoIdList;
var VideoName;
var pre8;


$(document).ready(function() {

    PlayVideoFromDropDown();
    videoIdList = GetVideoData();
    vidIndex = <%= VideoId %>;
    VideoName = '<% = VideoName %>';
    $("#taketest").hide();
    pre8 =  PreIe8();

    // The video to load.
    var videoID = videoIdList[vidIndex].youtubeId;





    console.log(videoID);
    $("#video_title").text(videoIdList[vidIndex].Name);



    if (true) {
        VideoSwitch(videoID);
        flagMovieWatched2(videoIdList[vidIndex].NewVideoId, vidIndex, videoIdList.length);
    }
});


function VideoSwitch(video) {



    // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
    var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
    // The element id of the Flash embed
    var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
    // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video + "?rel=0&autoplay=1&version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytPlayer",
        "ytPlayer", "520", "390", "9", null, null, params, atts);



}


function PlayVideoFromDropDown() {
    $("#videoSelection").on("change", function() {
        vidIndex = $(this).find(':selected').index();

        if (vidIndex > 0) {
            vidIndex = vidIndex - 1;
            $("#video_title").text(videoIdList[vidIndex].Name);

            if (true) {

                VideoSwitch(videoIdList[vidIndex].youtubeId);
                flagMovieWatched2(videoIdList[vidIndex].NewVideoId, vidIndex, videoIdList.length);

            } else {

                player.loadVideoById($(this).val());
            }

        }

    });

}

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

    if (!pre8) {
        console.log("Initialising API");
        player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
            height: '390',
            width: '520',
            enablejsapi: 1,
            playerVars: {
                'rel': 0,
                'modestbranding': 1
            },
            events:
                {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': ytStateChange
                }
        });

    }
}


function onPlayerReady() {
    console.log("vidIndex: " + vidIndex);
    playNextVideo();
}

function playVideoById(videoId) {
    console.log("video id = " + videoId);
    player.loadVideoById(videoId, 0, "default");
}

function playNextVideo() {
    console.log("Hi vid length = " + videoIdList.length);
    if (vidIndex < videoIdList.length) {
        var videoToPlay = videoIdList[vidIndex].youtubeId;
        console.log("Loading: " + videoToPlay);
        $("#video_title").text(videoIdList[vidIndex].Name);
        player.loadVideoById(videoToPlay, 0, "default");

    }
}

function GetVideoData() {
    var videoData = new Array();
    var video;
        <% foreach(var data in PlayListData) { %>
        video = new Object();
        video.id = '<%= data.VideoId %>';
        video.NewVideoId = '<%= data.NewVideoId %>';
        video.youtubeId = '<%= data.YoutubeVideoId %>';
        video.Name = '<%= data.Name %>';
        video.ModuleId = '<%= data.ModuleId %>';
        videoData.push(video);
        <% } %>
        return videoData;

    }


    function ytStateChange(state) {
        switch (state.data) {
            case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
                console.log("Video Ended");


                console.log("video stats" + videoIdList[vidIndex].id + " " + vidIndex + " " + videoIdList.length - 1);
                flagMovieWatched2(videoIdList[vidIndex].NewVideoId, videoIdList.length - 1);
                vidIndex++;
                playNextVideo();
                break;
            case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
                console.log("Video Playing");
                break;
            case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
                console.log("Video Paused");
                break;
            case YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING:
                console.log("Video Buffering");
                break;
            case YT.PlayerState.CUED:
                console.log("Video Queued");
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Unstarted");
                break;
        }

    }


    function flagMovieWatched2(movieId, movieIndex, playlistIndex) {
        $.post("<%= SiteSettings.PublicVirtualPath %>ajax/videos/flagvideo2.aspx",
            {
                param_movie: movieId,
                movieIndex: movieIndex,
                playlistIndex: playlistIndex
            }, function(data) {

                if (data == "true") {
                    showButton();
                }
            });
    }


    function showButton() {
        $("#taketest").fadeIn();
    }
```

Now we have just started tests on pc and Ipads, and yes PC works fine.  but unfortunately on the IPad all you get is a black box, the drop down effect on the player is still working which I find bizarre.

Need to find out why its not working on Ipad, it seems fine on PC and appears to be HTML5 which is whats wanted, but nothing on ipad.

Be warned I've been thrown onto this with very limited experience. Any help would be great thanks!

SIDE NOTE:  ive tried editing the code completely out and added my simple call and wrap to an iframe, which works but lose all the other functionality.

ive also tried removing the DIV that has the ID that calls this code and replaced it with a an Iframe wrap.  I think thats the reason i get the drop down effect but no video.

Additional, ive seen some information about the autoplay option cuasing the issue, i now i need to add autoplay=0 to the url, but im not sure how he builds it and where to slot this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is "Need to find out why its not working on Ipad", and here is my answer to that:

All those things about SWF and Flash will by design not work on ipad or iphone since SWF/Flash is blocked by Apple/iOS.

Comment: ah ok.  I looked into it and its said that its the fact its autoplay, this needs to be turned off. So i fi mange to find out where to turn of this property your saying it wont work regardless due to using swf? (cuz flash dont work on pad)

Comment: Yes you have to find some way without flash if you want it to work on ipad, such as html5 only without any flash.